RLM_ERR_SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED - Realm (MongoDB) schema validation issue with an array
I have a couple of simple RealmObject classes that look like this:
class Patient : RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
var firstName: String = ""
var lastName: String = ""
var visits: RealmList<PelletInsertionVisit> = realmListOf()
var lastFourOfSSN: String = ""
}

class PelletInsertionVisit : RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
var visitDate = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
var pelletsUsed: RealmList<Pellet> = realmListOf()
}

class Pellet: EmbeddedRealmObject {
var size = PelletSize.ZERO.value
var lotNumber: String = "UNKNOWN"
}

When I perform this code, the open throws an exception:
fun openPatientRealm() : Realm {
val configuration = RealmConfiguration.create(schema = setOf(Patient::class))
Logger.d("About to open Realm Configuration: $configuration")

try {
    val realm = Realm.open(configuration)  //EXCEPTION HERE

    Logger.d("Realm opened: : ${realm.toString()}")

    return realm
}
catch (ex: Exception) {
    Logger.e("Exception caught: " + ex.message)
    Logger.e("Stack trace: " + ex.stackTraceToString())
}

throw Exception("Realm Could Not be Opened")
}

The exception is:
[RLM_ERR_SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED]: Schema validation failed due to the following errors:

Property 'PelletInsertionVisit.pelletsUsed' of type 'array' has unknown object type 'Pellet'

What is it that I am doing wrong, please? It looks, to me, to be like the documentation says it should be using the EmbeddedRealmObject but I'm missing something.

Can you try changing class Patient() : RealmObject { to class Patient : RealmObject { and also change class PelletInsertionVisit() : RealmObject { to class PelletInsertionVisit : RealmObject {

It did not but I think what you suggested is needed though. I'm going to update what I have to reflect your suggestion open it up for a bounty.

Great. Now update the other code for your lists. Please replace var pelletsUsed: RealmList<Pellet> = realmListOf(Pellet()) with var pelletsUsed: RealmList<Pellet> = realmListOf().

Thanks for the suggestion, same result though.

I updated the code to reflect the latest I tried based on your last input.

Are you including all of the Realm classes when opening the Realm? Seems like some are omitted.

The problem was with the configuration. Long story short, you have to tell it all of the classes you intend to use. So, it went to:
val configuration = RealmConfiguration.create(schema = setOf(Patient::class, Pellet::class, PelletInsertionVisit::class, PelletLot::class))

